# How to filter missing data of spcific columns in pandas

Tags: pandas

I have data like:

```
     a              b        c

0  20120112        NaT    20120112

1  NaT             NaT    20120112

2  20120112        NaT    NaT
```

I want to filter out row "NaT NaT 20120112", because column a and column b are both NaT in that row. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use `notnull` to return a boolean Series of whether values are null (conversely `isnull` if they're not)

In your case, you would combine them with bitwise `&`:

```
df[df.a.notnull() & df.b.notnull()]
```

Comment: Could be possible to do anything like: `df[df['a', 'b'].notna().any(axis=1)]` ?

Answer (score 1):

I think what I need should be:

```
df[df.a.notnull() | df.b.notnull()]
```

Thanks, maxymoo